# looks like there is a bug in Google's implementation of createEventSeries

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

In the GAS description of createEventSeries https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createeventseriestitle,-starttime,-endtime,-recurrence
It shows the following code:

```
// Creates an event series for a team meeting, taking place every Tuesday and Thursday in 2013.
var eventSeries = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEventSeries('Team Meeting',
    new Date('January 1, 2013 03:00:00 PM EST'),
    new Date('January 1, 2013 04:00:00 PM EST'),
    CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule()
        .onlyOnWeekdays([CalendarApp.Weekday.TUESDAY, CalendarApp.Weekday.THURSDAY])
        .until(new Date('January 1, 2014')));
Logger.log('Event Series ID: ' + eventSeries.getId());
```

But when I execute this code it also creates an extra event on 1/1/2013. I believe this extra event shouldn't have been created and neither does the comment in this code.
Am I missing something? If not, what's the best way to report this so Google sees it?
Thanks.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: I was able to reproduce your issue for 2023-2024 with the extra event on 1/1/24.  I would suggest you report to [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)

Comment: Thanks TheWizEd. I would report to Google Issue Tracker, but I'm not authorized. Someone with more cred will have to do it.

Comment: This also explains the problem I reported in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73340674/creating-recurring-calendar-event-for-a-year-is-creating-one-extra-on-1-1-how-d

Comment: @mdy no authorization needed to create a issue. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for correct link of the tracker

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've created an Issue Tracker for this.

Comment: @mdy You may add a answer with the link like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+issue+is+reported+)